# Given the IPs of all on my network, how can I find their computer names?

Tags: networking, ip

I obtained a list of all IPs in my network with `fing` (linux package for analyzing networks).

How can I obtain the names of the machines? And maybe could I obtain the OS too?

Answer (score 2):

The computer name can be a bit tricky depending on the OS in use. If it's a fully qualified domain name, as in, proper DNS record exists for it, you can just do a reverse lookup: `nslookup 192.168.0.123` where you of course use the correct IP address.

If it's that windows network name thingy (of which I do not know the proper protocol name. SMB?), then I've noticed that Windows looks this up automatically if you do a `tracert 192.168.0.123`

nmap allows you to try fingerprint the OS: `nmap -O 192.168.0.0/24`

Comment: It's not the Windows thing. It's a Linux tool, fing: overlooksoft.com/features for analyzing networks.

Comment: @JeannoBentoir Yes, I am aware of fing. By "windows thing" I mean the name you're after, if it's the windows share name or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the names of the computers if you have a DNS server with your DCHP, for the os you would need a software like deksi network inventory

Comment: Your answer says it's possible but doesn't explain how to do it (which is what the question asked).  Can you expand your answer?